# how to prove that the curvature of sin x is greatest at its extremum?

Tags: calculus

how to prove that the curvature of sin x is greatest at its extremum?  I've done several approaches but couldn't see a concrete solution that proves it well.

Comment: The curvature is measured by the second derivative.

Comment: @Arthur According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature that is actually an approximation used when the slope is "small compared to unity"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to understand curvature ($\kappa$) by defining it as the multiplicative inverse of the radius of curvature ($1/\kappa$).

Take a point on a function (x, f(x)) and draw a line normal (i.e. perpendicular to the line tangent at that point) at that point; do the same for the point (x+h, f(x+h)) and calculate the point where they intersect (the point of intersection will approach the center of curvature as $h\to 0$). Now find the distance between the center of curvature and (x, f(x)). It may be productive to review the "trick" used in proving the product rule for derivatives (https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/prodrule/proof.html).

You should end up with the formula on this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_(mathematics)

I used the following diagram to help me the first time I tried it. 
[image]

That being done, it's just a simple matter of optimizing the curvature function ($\kappa(x)$) for the sine function.

Answer (score 6):

The curvature $\kappa(x)$ of a curve $y=f(x)$ is given by
$$\kappa(x)={|f''(x)|\over(1+f'^2(x)\bigr)^{3/2}}\ .$$
When $y=\sin x$ one immediately gets the estimate
$$\kappa(x)\leq1$$
with equality iff $|\sin''(x)|=|\sin x|=1$ and $\sin'(x)=\cos x=0$.